# Have I correctly taken this function $f(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{1+2x}$ and $f ' (x) $and turned them into power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^{2}}{1+2x}$

To turn this into a power series I recall the similar looking geometric series,

$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^5 +\cdots$

And not I can mutate my original function to fit the form the geometric series:

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^{2}}{1-(-2x)}$

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{1}*\dfrac{x^{2}}{1-(-2x)} = 1 + (-2x) + (-2x)^{2} + (-2x)^{3} + (-2x)^{4} +\cdots$

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{1}*\dfrac{x^{2}}{1-(-2x)} = 1 - 2x + 4x^2 - 8x^3 + 16x^4 +\cdots$

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{1}*\dfrac{x^{2}}{1-(-x^{2})} = x^2( 1 - 2x + 4x^2 - 8x^3 + 16x^4 +\cdots)$

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{1}*\dfrac{x^{2}}{1-(-x^{2})} = x^2 - 2x^3 + 4x^4 -8x^5 + 16x^{6} +\cdots)$

And for $'(x)$

$f'(x) = 2x - 6x^2 + 16x^3 -40x^4 + 16*6x^{5} +\cdots$

Is this right or wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Oh boy...yep it was supposed to be the way I had it in the question. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:
$$
\frac{1}{2x+1} \approx 1 - 2 x + 4 x^2 - 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 - 32 x^5 +\mathcal{O}\left( x^{6} \right)
$$
Now multiply by $x^{2}$.

$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2 x+1} \approx x^2 -2 x^3+4 x^4-8 x^5+ \mathcal{O}\left( x^{6} \right)
$$

---

Suggestion:
$$ 
\frac{1}{(2 x+1)^2} \approx 1 - 4 x + 12 x^2 - 32 x^3 + 80 x^4 - 192 x^5 + \mathcal{O}\left( x^{6} \right)
$$
Multiply by $2 x (1 + x) = 2 x^2+2 x$:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2 x (x+1)}{(2 x+1)^2} \approx 2 x - 6 x^2 + 16 x^3 - 40 x^4 + 96 x^5+ \mathcal{O}\left( x^{6} \right)
$$

---

@law-of-fives suggests partial fraction decomposition:

$$
f(x) =\frac{x^2}{2 x+1} = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4 (2 x+1)}-\frac{1}{4}
$$

A more elegant solution!

Comment: For $\frac{x^2}{1+2x}$ can we first find a quotient and remainder $\frac{x^2}{1+2x} = \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{1+2x}$ and then tack on the power series for $\frac{1}{1+2x}$ in place of that term?

Comment: Thanks!! I rewrote my solution with your suggestions. How does it look?

Comment: @yre: Looks great. I hope you used the great insight by law-of-fives.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach based upon the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots
\end{align*}

is fine  and appropriate. Just the calculations are not correct in all aspects.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{1+2x}\\
> &=x^2\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-2x)}\\
> &=x^2\left(1-2x+4x^2-8x^3+16x^4-\cdots\right)\\
> &=x^2-2x^3+4x^4-8x^4+16x^6-\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> and  from (1)  we derive  the  derivative of $f$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f^\prime(x)=2x-6x^2+16x^3-32x^3+72x^5-\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance with your calculation.